# How to use mathematical induction here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction

Is a well known fact that $\mathbb{H} \cong \mathrm{Ass}(\{x,y\})/\langle x^2+1, y^2+1, xy+yx\rangle$, where $\mathrm{Ass}(\{x,y\})$ is the free associative algebra generated by $\{x,y\}$, and $\langle x^2+1, y^2+1, xy+yx\rangle$ denotes the ideal generated by the three elements within $\langle\ \rangle$.

The proof I'm reading uses the universal property of $\mathrm{Ass}(\{x,y\})$. First, consider the function $\phi:\{x,y\} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ defined by $x \mapsto i$, $y \mapsto j$. By the universal property, it can be extended to an Algebra homomorphism $\Gamma: \mathrm{Ass}(\{x,y\}) \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$. Now, the goal is to prove that $\ker(\Gamma) = \langle x^2+1, y^2+1, xy+yx\rangle$. The containment "$\supseteq$" is trivial. For the another ("$\subseteq$") I know that it can be proved using mathematical induction by the following way:

1. The linear combinations of degree 1 (*i.e* $\alpha x +\beta y$ ) are not in $\ker(\Gamma)$.
2. the linear combinations of degree 2 in $\ker(\Gamma)$ are all in $\langle x^2+1, y^2+1, xy+yx\rangle$.
3. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, If I suppose that all linear combinations of degree $2 \leq k < n$ that are in are $\ker(\Gamma)$ are in $\langle x^2+1, y^2+1, xy+yx\rangle$ too, then all linear combinations of degree $n$ are in $\langle x^2+1, y^2+1, xy+yx\rangle$. (**Inductive step**).

My question is about the inductive step. How can I prove that? I tried a lot of things, but... I couldn't.

**Edit:** The elements of $Ass(\{x,y\})$ are linear combinations of words in the alphabet $\{x,y\}$. By degree $k$, I mean words of length $k$; for instance, if $k=4$, $xyxy,xy^2x$ are words of length $k$.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are doing, or what “linear combinations of degree $k$” means. You are trying to prove that $\ker(\Gamma)\subseteq \langle x^2+1,y^2+1,xy+yx\rangle$. Why are you trying to prove that some things are in $\ker(\Gamma)$? Shouldn’t you be trying to prove that things are in the ideal generated by $x^2+1$, $y^2+1$, and $xy+yx$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The elements of $Ass(\{x,y\})$ are linear combinations of words in the alphabet $\{x,y\}$. By degree $k$, I mean words of length $k$; for instance, if $k = 4$, $xyxy, xy^2x$ are words of length $k$.

Comment: Yes, but why are you trying to prove something is in the kernel of $\Gamma$? You are supposed to be proving that if something is in the kernel of $\Gamma$, *then* it is in the ideal $\langle x^2+1,y^2+1,xy+yx\rangle$. Instead, you say you want to prove that some things are in $\ker(\Gamma)$. That shouldn’t be the goal to prove what you say you are trying to prove.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, It was a content error. I've just fixed it.

Comment: Now your first point makes no sense. If you have things in $\ker(\Gamma)$ that are not in $\langle x^2+1,y^2+1,xy+yx\rangle$, then you do *not* have $\ker(\Gamma)\subseteq \langle x^2+1,y^2+1,xy+yx\rangle$. I *think* you meant to say something like “no linear combination of elements of $\mathrm{Ass}(\{x,y\})$ lie in $\ker(\Gamma)$” or something like that...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, The idea is to exclude them from the mathematical induction... I've just fixed it...